# How to load a webpack React bundle with SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, systemjs

I have a main React application and I create webpack bundled React libraries that can be loaded dynamically in the main app upon user request or as a result of some user actions.

I thought using SystemJS to dynamically load the librairies was the way to go but I can't find any pointers on the topic.

Here is my issue:

If I bundle the library with React dependencies, I can load the file with SystemJS but I'm getting this error:

> invariant.js:44 Uncaught (in promise) Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

This makes sense since React as been included in my bundle and is also part of the main App. So I thought excluding React from the lib will solve the problem. I added the "external" to my webpack config:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Webpack config development
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module.exports = {

  devtool: 'source-map',

  context: path.join(
    __dirname, '../src/Extensions'),

  entry: {
    Extension: [
      './Extension/index.js'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "[name]"
  },

  plugins: [

    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        WEBPACK: true
      }
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      _: 'lodash',
      $: 'jquery',

      React: "React",
      react: "React",
      "window.react": "React",
      "window.React": "React"
    }),

    new ProgressBarPlugin({
      format: '  build [:bar] ' + chalk.green.bold(':percent') + ' (:elapsed seconds)',
      clear: false
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./node_modules'),
    ],
    extensions : ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  },

  module: {

    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime']
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },

  externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  }
}
```

But after doing so, loading the lib with SystemJS will output the following error:

> ConfiguratorView.js:116 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>           at eval ()
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/React
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/Extension.js
>           at eval ()

I understand SystemJS is attempting to load the React dependency at localhost:3000/React and from what I read this has to be configured with SystemJS.config({...}) but the question is how?? I read the SystemJS config documentation, but I haven't seen any example like so.

Am I the only one trying to dynamically load a React library? Is there a better approach? I want to have a flexible mechanism in place so unecessary libraries can be loaded on demand and do not bloat the main bundle.

Thanks for any pointer on that

Answer (score -1):

Use a debundler or webpack as a browserify plugin to map the package names and locations to the SystemJS configuration files:

> SystemJS is meant to work with any module definition specifications, and even a repository URL. This means when SystemJS encounters a require('module_name') or an import module_name, it doesn't know where to find the module called module_name. Would it be on npm? Or is it a custom repository? SystemJS can't know for sure.
>
> So we'd need to provide a mapping of all packages' names and the location of their repository. Needless to say, doing this manually is impractical, so we must use another package manager, that manages packages from everywhere.

**References**

- [Build a React Application from First Principles - Modules + SystemJS](http://blog.brew.com.hk/build-a-react-application-from-first-principles-modules-with-systemjs/)
- [Stack update 2016: Future-proofing our javascript bundling with webpack 2 and rollup | Signal Agency Linz](https://www.signalonline.at/en/blog/building-with-webpack-and-rollup)
- [How to bundle Syncfusion ReactJS components using webpack and browserify? | JavaScript | Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7547/how-to-bundle-syncfusion-reactjs-components-using-webpack-and-browserify)
- [shama/webpackify: Use webpack through a Browserify plugin](https://github.com/shama/webpackify)
- [1egoman/debundle: A javascript debundler. Takes a Browserify or Webpack bundle and recreates the initial, pre-bundled source.](https://github.com/1egoman/debundle)